# How to set the right to see a view in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am logged in as user "a" in my oracle database.
I can write a query like "Select * from MyView" and I get all results - thats fine.
BUT I can't see the view itself in SqlDeveloper in my View-tree (list), additional to that I am not the owner (which I can see with "Select * from all_views").

How can I change the rights of this view to see "MyVIew" in the tree?

Comment: Thats odd . The fact the you can select from the view implies you have `view` access to that view. If you are not the owner of the view than you have to go to the schema of the owner to see the view. In order to see the view under your view "tree" you would have to be the owner of the view. i.e `create view yourschema.viewname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Littlefoot is correct in his answer. You could of course also browse to the view directly via the 'Other Users' portion of the tree, then drill down into the Views.

BUT, you could also just set your Views filter to 'Include Synonyms'

[I wrote a story on this topic for TABLES, but it also applies to VIEWS here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I presume you should query `all_objects` to see what you're actually dealing with. Why? Because of the following example:

Connected as user `mike`, I'll create a table, grant select on it to public and create a public synonym:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> create table test as select 'Littlefoot' name from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create public synonym myview for test;

Synonym created.

SQL> grant select on test to public;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as another user, `scott` and select from `myview`:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> select * from myview;

NAME
----------
Littlefoot
```

Right; it works. Where is it in SQL Developer?

[image]

Aha, it is in **public synonyms** (I applied filter on name, looking for `MYVIEW` to skip *zillion* other public synonyms).

Or, in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type, owner from all_objects where object_name = 'MYVIEW';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------
MYVIEW                         SYNONYM             PUBLIC

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, I suggest you do the same - query all_objects and you'll know something more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can not change the right of the view to see it your View-tree (list), because it is not your own object. To have the view in your  View-tree (list) you have to create it in your own shema.